# How to add a CSS arrow to an absolutely positioned element

Tags: css

Many time I've successfully used [the cssarrowplease technique](http://cssarrowplease.com/) which imposes the main element (not the arrow) to be relatively positioned. However this time the element I want to add an arrow to is already absolutely positioned.

How to fix this dilemma?

EDIT: here's my code:

HTML

```
<li id="submenu">
    <div id="enquiries_popup">
        <div id="enquiries_popup_content">
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

CSS

```
li#submenu {
    position: relative;
}
#enquiries_popup {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#enquiries_popup_content {
    background: #000;
}
#enquiries_popup_content:after { 
    bottom: 100%; 
    left: 50%; 
    border: solid transparent; 
    content: " "; 
    height: 0; 
    width: 0; 
    position: absolute; 
    pointer-events: none; 
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    border-bottom-color: #000000; 
    border-width: 8px; 
    margin-left: -8px; 
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, It's late I know, Your are right it does not show up because the position is absolute, and the arrow rectangles go out of the box, if you set the bottom to 50% for example you'll see them. 
The solution is to put this div in another div with position absolute and give it some padding, then set the popup div position to relative and it will work!

```
<li id="submenu">
   <div id="absolute_div">
     <div id="enquiries_popup">
      <div id="enquiries_popup_content">
        Content
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </li>
```

css

```
#enquiries_popup {
position: relative;
padding-top: 30px;
}
#absolute_div {
position: absolute;
padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work just fine for your absolutely positioned element. Next time, try it before asking!

All the arrow trick requires is for your element to *be positioned* in the first place in order for the arrow position to be relative to it. It works with relative, absolute and fixed positioning alike.

Comment: That was some easy rep. :)

Comment: Well it works and it doesn't. The arrow gets positioned relatively to the wrong element: not "#enquiries_popup_content" as I want but to its parent "#enquiries_popup". Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @drake035: So put `position: relative;` on your other element then.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: the other element is absolutely positioned.